# Draw order in Android RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView where I have enabled dragging to swap item order, however there's an issue with the draw order, sometimes when I am dragging one of the rows it is drawn under the other rows, instead of above them (this seems to happen most often when dragging an item down the list).

Is there a way to make sure that the view that is being dragged is always rendered on top of the other views?

Comment: can you share the code ?